# Visual Studio 2010: Browse for file dialog doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm encountering a really weird error in Visual Studio 2010. The browse for file location dialog won't show. I first noticed it when I tried to add an existing file (a jpeg) as a resource. Now I've noticed that it's the same problem when I try to File - Open - Project/Solution. Nothing happens.

I've tried restarting the program, restarting my PC, and re-installing VS.

This is really weird. And I can't seem to find anything on Google.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you have to start the TabletPCInput service in services.msc.

Comment: Found this after an hour of googling. The same happened to me when running virtualbox, W10 host with a W7 guest, with visual studio 2010 in the guest OS. Could not vote up more, thanks a lot!

Comment: Upvoted! Solved the problem here with a virtualbox Windows 7 VM running VS2012. Thanks a lot!